# xcodebuild error while generating xcframework library

Tags: macos, static, frameworks, xcode11

I'm trying to create xcframework of j2objc built by make dist.

Presumerbly those .a files are compiled as fat library, but built with xCode10 due to compile errors when compile with xCode11.

My build environments are xCode11 beta 2 and MacOS 10.5 beta.

```
$ xcodebuild -create-xcframework -library ./lib/libjre_emul.a -library ./lib/macosx/libjre_emul.a -headers ./include/ -output lib/universal/libjre_emul.xcframework

error: binaries with multiple platforms are not supported './j2objc/dist/lib/libjre_emul.a'
```

Comment: Do you have a library that was already combined with lipo?  Perhaps for simulator and iOS builds?

Comment: By searching for Make files for days. I found that the file is build as fat lib using lipo. I succeeded to make xcframework file using built .a files found in build_result folders. The library files in build_results are all in the previous stage before using lipo command from Makefile.